# Flipping (orthographic) camera axes

Tags: three.js

It seems possible to flip an axes of an orthographic camera in three, e.g. by the following code:

```
var tmp = camera.right;
camera.right = camera.left;
camera.left = tmp;
camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
```

However, this screws up the lighting, so it seems to not be supported (at least not with built in materials). Is this so? Is there another way to achieve this?

The use case I currently have is a scientific scene (loads of spheres and lines) that can be seen from either positive or negative Z direction. The requirement is that the X and Y axis point the same direction (e.g. right and up) no matter which Z-direction you are looking in. Is there an alternative solution if flipping left/right is not the way to go?

For an example of what I am talking about, see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mt0bpwcz/1/  Try double clicking the scene to switch the camera. Afterwards the lighting will be very strange (especially visible in the specular highlights).

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your requirement about the X and Y axes... When you do this, the X axis _does_ flip. It **must** flip. You can't view the data from +Z _AND_ -Z, and expect the X and Y axes to remain in the same direction.

Comment: If you see the example fiddle, it is capable of doing that, but I guess it is not very happy with breaking the right-hand-rule. I guess this question is related to other questions where people try to scale an object with a negative scale (they need double sided drawing + normal inversion as well).

Comment: I looked at your fiddle, and the green and blue spheres swap places on double-click, which means if your +X axis initially points right, the double click makes +X point left. I know you said you'll have a lot of objects in the scene, but you could potentially just loop through all of them and negate their Z positions `object.position.z *= -1;`. That operations would only be as expensive as the number of objects, and would only occur on the double-clicks.

Comment: In the fiddle they swap places, which is expected when the Z-direction does not also change (if I add that, it would keep pointing to the right). What the fiddle demonstrates is that the lighting gets screwed up when you switch the left and right of the ortho camera.

Comment: See an updated fiddle here that also switches Z side by moving the camera: https://jsfiddle.net/vidartf/mt0bpwcz/3/

Comment: set `.material.side = THREE.FrontSide` on one and `THREE.BackSide` on the other.